# Inverse Laplace Transformation of incomplete gamma function in julia

Tags: python, julia, inverse, mpmath

Recently, I have a problem in julia related with inverse laplace.

Here is the code that I write in julia.

```
using SpecialFunctions
using InverseLaplace

value = Talbot(u -> gamma_inc(1,u,2)[2], 80)
value(2)
```

This code make some error message like

```
MethodError: no method matching gamma_inc(::Float64, ::BigFloat, ::Int64, ::String)
```

Actually, I can calculate that kind of function in python already, based on mpmath.

```
import mpmath as mp

laplace = lambda u: mp.gammainc(1,u)
result = mp.invertlaplace(laplace, t = 2, method= 'talbot',degree = 80)

print(result)
```

and the result is

```
5.6730679553874e-43
```

I want to solve this problem on julia, and is there anyone who can give me any suggestion?

p.s. Sorry for my bad English. Hope you understand it..